# Can I run a java program using local storage for ram?

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, ram

So, I have EXTREMELY low RAM and the program gets killed if I use to much of it.  My question is: Can I run a java program using local storage for ram?  I am using amazon ec2 to host.  It is a Micro Server.

Comment: So you are trying to emulate Swap *within Java*?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what 'Swap' is.  Guess who is the beginner!

Comment: Swap is used to use disk space as RAM. It should be already done at the OS level. I don't know why EC2 doesn't provide swap...

Comment: that was my problem too, but not at ec2. I have asked the hosting admin and he changed my filesystem, don't know to which one, but that allowed more RAM usage at startup and also allowed the swap, my problem was solved with that. Here is was my hosting: http://www.interserver.net/vps

Comment: I think the proper answer is: yes, it can be done, **but don't do it**. Otherwise the performance of your app will drop to appalling levels and amazon is going to charge you for all the IO operations you're doing on disk.

Comment: You might try playing with serializing the objects to disk and using weak references for the data model, but you will have to provide a way to restore the objects deleted from disk when you need them. I agree with Augusto, not worth the effort. Contract a better setup.